# GIS mapping tool on detailed scale

Tags: mapping, geolocation, gis

I'm looking for good GIS solutions that work on a relatively smaller, detailed scale. Specifically, I was wondering what APIs or toolkits are available for mapping out spaces in a building (like rooms, hallways, shelves). This need not be a 3D solution, like one might envisage for architectural CAD-type drawings. Something relatively lightweight would be ideal.

I feel like ArcGIS is a bit of overkill for that, though I may very well be wrong.

Since it's mapping but not quite GPS/routing/distance/Earth/road-type mapping I'm in a bit of a quandary.

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: You might get a better answer at the [new GIS stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary between GIS and CAD softwares depends on the scale and level of detail of your data. GIS are said more suitable for topographic scales (less than 1:10000) with simplified 2D representations, and CAD softs for bigger scales (more then 1:10000) with very detailled representations, usually in 3D. Nevertheless, there is a convergence between both: GIS supports more and more 3D representations, and CAD softs provide some spatial analysis features.

If your purpose is to build a 3D model, I will suggest you a CAD software like [blender](http://www.blender.org/). You can also have a look at [sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/) or the tools used to build [citygml](http://www.citygml.org/) data.

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS is available for many solutions, just check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS).

Comment: Does PostGIS support 3D geometries?

Comment: Yes it does: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/reference.html#PostGIS_Types